# is there a setting to filter out variables from breadcrumbs in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've taken a look at [navigation docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) and played with the possible breadcrumb settings in but none of them seem to allow filtering

As it is now, breadcrumbs outline is littered with variables from function signatures and that's not really useful to me. It litters the list and makes it harder to find function names (likewise with outline)

[image: the blue icon is for variables]

Answer (score 16):

Yes, [with VSCode 1.40](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_type-filters-for-outline-and-breadcrumbs) (October 2019)

> ### Type filters for outline and breadcrumbs
>
> There are new settings to configure what symbols are displayed in the Outline view and breadcrumb navigation.
>
> The settings are called `outline.show{symbol type}` and `breadcrumbs.show{symbol type}`.
> For example, `outline.showVariables`, `outline.showFunctions`, etc.

[image: Filtered Outline view]

> The screen shot above shows the Outline view configured to not show local variables and you can see that the variable hidden isn't shown.
>
> Note that it's up to the language extension to assign the type of a symbol.
> You can hover over the symbol label in the Outline view to see which symbol type is being used (shown in parentheses).

Comment: 1.4.0 seems to have more sensible defaults, so it was nice that it hid the variables without needing to change any settings at all